# Private Tangle spawns unissued messages

Tags: tangle, private-network

I set up my own private tangle and it works well.

Then I shut down the spammer in order to control the messages issued, anyway, there are messages with indexation payload emitted periodically and I can't figure out who is issuing them.

These messages are not Milestones, they are just messages with an index and no data.

Where can I search ?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have multiple nodes with the spammer plugin active and only disabled one of them?